# Hi guys how can i print in #Ausgabe with a button click

Tags: javascript, html

i will create a Checkout system for gastro.
How i can wríte this.
I will create a list than write this on another page "home.php",
than i need a script were i can onclick writeout "deftige KartoffelSuppe" and the price.
i love you guys,

```
 <script>
    let Suppe =["Deftige Kartoffelsuppe, 4,80"];
    </script>
        <button id="btn0">Deftige Kartoffelsuppe</button>
    <div id="Ausgabe"></div>
```

Greedings from Germany

Michael Burat

Comment: Hi Michael, I see you previously asked a number of questions that were either closed or downvoted like this one. I suggest reviewing [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Hope this will help you getting help from this website!

Comment: Hi guys this must be stack

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn0">Deftige Kartoffelsuppe</button>
    <div id="ausgabe"></div>
    <script>
      let suppe = ["Deftige Kartoffelsuppe, 4,80"];
      const btn = document.querySelector("#btn0");
      const ausgabe = document.querySelector("#ausgabe");
      btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        ausgabe.innerHTML = suppe;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i changed the id names to lowercase and added a eventListener to handle the click.
innerHTML is what you wanted i guess.
And thanks for loving me btw.

and this is a clean version of coding something like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn0">Deftige Kartoffelsuppe</button>
    <div id="ausgabe"></div>
    <script>
      const data = [
        {
          name: "Deftige Kartoffelsuppe",
          preis: "4,80€"
        }
      ];
      const btn = document.querySelector("#btn0");
      const ausgabe = document.querySelector("#ausgabe");
      btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        ausgabe.innerHTML = `${data[0].name} für nur ${data[0].preis}`;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How i can stack this

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I will stack this when the button is clicked new

Comment: how would you do that? give me a hint. show me some code examples of what you mean.

Comment: if i click this button again dann stack the preis and a number

Comment: And than its more than Deftige Kartoffelsuppe, Rübchen suppe , 4.00€, Tante Mariechen 4,50